# What is the unit of entropy with different log base?

Tags: interpretation, entropy

Entropy is the measure of randomness of a random variable.
$$H(X) = -\sum_{x\in X}p(x)\log_{2}(p(x))$$

The units when using the $\log_{2}$ is bits i.e., how many bits required to store the information present in the random variable $X$.

What will be the units of entropy when use other base for log i.e., natural log/log base 10 or any other? How we will interpret those units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For natural log the units are called "*nats*". 
I believe it's just a convention to define entropy with natural log and it probably stems from thermodynamic entropy which uses nats for convenience: as wiki puts it ["Physical systems of natural units that normalize Boltzmann's constant to 1 are effectively measuring thermodynamic entropy in nats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)).

As the main concern about entropy is its role in definition of mutual information between random variables, there's no practical effect of using different bases for log.

Comment: +1 Nice response. My question may seem like a bit of a tangent but here it is. In a recent paper by Lin and Tegmark, *Critical Behavior from Deep Dynamics*, available here ... https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/5ba0/3a03d844f10d7b4861d3b116818afe2b75f2.pdf , they discuss the consequences for NLP models in positing distributional assumptions involving "nat" processes and, specifically, what this can mean for truly power-lawed processes and information-theoretic metrics such as Kullback-Leibler divergence. Extending that to entropy, do you think their concerns are relevant-is the "nat" right?